# How to round extruded text and keep original contour?

Tags: text-object

If you start with basic extruded text:

[image]

Then you add a rounding bevel on it you can bubble it out like this:

[image]

But of course this makes the text much bigger so the letters are all fat and bumping into each other.

Is there any way to apply a "rounding"/bubble effect to the front facing aspect of the font without making it giant and fat like this?

For example, if I apply a negative bevel I can get:

[image]

Which is sort of what I want - the outline of the font is the same but there is now a 3D effect to the surface. Problem is it's a sharp bevel effect and I want a smoothly contoured one.

Is there any way to get a bubble effect without changing the contour of the text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to equally decrease *Offset* parametr under *Geometry* properties ...
Like for *Depth* **0.02** use *Offset* **-0.02**

[image]

... but anyway Jachym's suggestion is better (convert to mesh, clean topology and use modifiers) ... it is more predictable and controllable :)

Answer (score 6):

It expands to avoid clashing with the messy geometry of editable text.

To get a 'normal' bevel, you need to use the Bevel modifier.
And probably clean up the messy geometry before that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Solidify / Remesh / Laplacian Smooth* worked quite well for "bubble" text :)
(in this old 2.8x)

[image]

Laplacian Smooth modifier – disable **Preserve Volume** and **Normalized**